# Changing the color of dots on BX Slider

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to play with colors in the AccessPress Basic template for WordPress (http://accesspressthemes.com/theme-demos/?theme=accesspress-basic) and I am trying to change the color for the BX-Slider navigation "dots" from red to other color.
I've changed it for active "dot" with:

```
.bx-pager-link.active:before {
   background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

However I cannot change it also for the hover, I tried with that:

```
.bx-pager-link.hover:before {
  background-color: #fff !important;

}
```

But it does not work.

I'd appreciate any help

Comment: I am really curious to know who's the genius who closed this as no code! `:P`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a specificity issue. Try this:

```css
.ap-basic-slider-wrapper .bx-pager-item .bx-pager-link.active:before,
.ap-basic-slider-wrapper .bx-pager-item .bx-pager-link:hover:before {
  background: #fff;
}
```

See that I have used two things:

1. Full path.
2. `background` instead of `background-color`.

Works perfectly for me, make sure you load it after the `styles.css` or at the end of `styles.css`:

[image]

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know, Praveen, how to change the Toggle Content field in AP Toggle Section so that it accepts html? (perhaps I should start a new thread, but I always get -1s :(